# ReCaptcha returns 400 Bad Request during the verification

Tags: php, recaptcha, guzzle

I’m trying to use Google’s reCaptcha and getting «400 Bad Request»
during verification process.
To communicate with Google I use Guzzle PHP HTTP client, like this:

```
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client(['defaults' => ['verify' => false]]);
$res = $client->get('https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify',
    ['body' => [
            'secret' =>  'my secret key',
            'response' => Input::get('g-recaptcha-response')
        ]]);
```

Does anybody know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That API endpoint takes a POST request and you are sending a GET request.

Comment: Off course you’re right! Thank you!
How could I be so careless…